# In javascript, how do I copy all properties of an object into a block's variable scope?

Tags: javascript, scope

Is there a way to add to a function or a block's variable scope in javascript in an automated manner? If so, how?

For instance, let's say I had some unit test code like this:

```
describe('something something', function () {
    // tested module
    let myTestedModule;

    before(function () {
        myTestedModule = rewire('../../path/to/my-tested-module');
    });

    // tested module dependencies
    let someRandomLib;
    let myDBAdapter;
    let util;
    let common;

    const restoreFunctions = [];

    beforeEach(function () {
        restoreFunctions.push(myTestedModule.__set__('someRandomLib', new Mock()));
        restoreFunctions.push(myTestedModule.__set__('myDBAdapter', new Mock()));
        restoreFunctions.push(myTestedModule.__set__('util', new Mock()));
        restoreFunctions.push(myTestedModule.__set__('common', new Mock()));
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        lodash.forEach(restoreFunctions, function (restore) {
            restore();
        });
    });

    // tests
    it('should do some amazing things', function (done) {
        // tested call
        myTestedModule.doStuff('foo', 'bar');

        // assertions
        someRandomLib.asdf.should.be.calledWithExactly('foo');

        // done
        done();
    });
});
```

Most of this actual code would be repeated in multiple tests, and it's trivial to simplify it to something like this:

```
describe('something something', function () {
    const testEnv = new TestEnvironment({
        module: 'myTestedModule',
        path: '../../path/to/my-tested-module',
        dependencies: ['someRandomLib', 'myDBAdapter', 'util', 'common'],
    });

    it('should do some amazing things', function (done) {
        // tested call
        testEnv.myTestedModule.doStuff('foo', 'bar');

        // assertions
        testEnv.someRandomLib.asdf.should.be.calledWithExactly('foo');

        // done
        done();
    });
});
```

However, the test would be better in terms of readability if I could omit most of the `testEnv` indexing. It's just plumbing, not part of the actual test.

So, to get the best of both worlds, what I really wanted to write was something like this:

```
describe('something something', function () {
    setupTestEnvironment({
        module: 'myTestedModule',
        path: '../../path/to/my-tested-module',
        dependencies: ['someRandomLib', 'myDBAdapter', 'util', 'common'],
    });

    it('should do some amazing things', function (done) {
        // tested call
        myTestedModule.doStuff('foo', 'bar');

        // assertions
        someRandomLib.asdf.should.be.calledWithExactly('foo');

        // done
        done();
    });
});
```

To do this, I need a way to import an object's own properties into a variable scope (i.e. this function's variable scope).

In Python you can achieve this with decorators. In Lua you can do this with `_M` or `setfenv`. Is it possible at all in Javascript?

Comment: This is not possible (except with non-strict `eval`).

Comment: Couldn't destructuring do it? you'd of course have to specify what you wanted to take from it.

Comment: @KevinB Yep, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for, having to specifiy what I want to take from it is not a problem! Could you add it as an answer so that I can mark it as resolved?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this would be a good case for [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
it('should do some amazing things', function (done) {
    const {myTestedModule, someRandomLib} = testEnv;

    // tested call
    myTestedModule.doStuff('foo', 'bar');

    // assertions
    someRandomLib.asdf.should.be.calledWithExactly('foo');

    // done
    done();
});
```